# How to measure the peak startup current for an electric motor?

Tags: ac, current-measurement

How would I measure the startup current for an electric motor?

For greater context, see https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194224/what-kind-of-inverter-do-i-need-for-an-inductive-load/194227?noredirect=1#comment345387_194227

The general problem is that I need to size an inverter to run a portable AC unit. I have a clamp meter and line splitter that I can easily use to test steady-state current at various temperatures and loads. However, I'm not sure if the response time will be enough to catch the actual peak load when the compressor starts.

Comment: It won't be fast enough. I suppose you could measure the resistance and go I = V/R? But then you still have no idea how long that startup current actually lasts and it takes current time to ramp up so it may never get to the level that you measured.

Comment: It may be unworkable for you but I have often thought that compressors would benefit from being driven with three phase motors and three phase inverters (variable frequency drives) so that they can have slow start under load with greatly reduced peak current.

Comment: If you are using an inverter drive on a motor, the inverter drive eliminates the kind of peak starting current you see without them. It's inherent in how they work.

Comment: The plan is to use an inverter similar to https://www.amazon.com/KRI%C3%8BGER-Installation-appliances-According-Standards/dp/B07MS5BY6T/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=1100+watt+inverter&qid=1591129341&s=automotive&sr=1-4 to power a portable AC intended to run off of normal house power in the USA.

Comment: @mkeith Compressors do benefit from VFD control. Inverter drive AC is commercially available.

Comment: @JRaef perhaps clarification from the OP would be warranted. If this is a VFD, often called an inverter, then yes. But if this is a single phase output inverter with low voltage DC input of 48V or below, then no. OP will need to deal with very high startup current for single-phase motor with start cap.

Comment: @Elros The 12 Vdc - 110 Vac inverter you linked to on Amazon is a different class of inverter to the variable frequency drive (VFD) type of inverter mentioned in other comments.

Comment: I’m assuming that I will have to deal with the high startup current. Since I have the AC unit, I’m trying to measure how high that current is to either size my inverter or decide it is too expensive and find an alternate plan.